# How to return values from a threaded watchservice

Tags: java

I have a class that looks in a specific folder for new image files that have been moved there. How can I return the names of these files back to my main class so that I can manipulate the images once they've been moved into the folder?

In my main class I have

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new DirectoryWatcher(directory.toPath()));
thread.start();
```

And the DirectoryWatcher class

```
public class DirectoryWatcher implements Runnable{

private Path path;
private FileSystem fs;
private WatchKey watchKey;
private Path newFile;
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9-_\\s()]+.(jpg|png|bmp|JPG|PNG|BMP)");
private Matcher matcher;
private String patternMatcher;

public DirectoryWatcher(Path path){

    this.path = path;
    fs = this.path.getFileSystem();
    watchKey = null;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        Boolean isFolder = (boolean) Files.getAttribute(path, "basic:isDirectory", NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
        if(!isFolder) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path: " + path + " is not a folder");
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Watching directory: " + path);

    try(WatchService service = fs.newWatchService()) {
        path.register(service, ENTRY_CREATE);

        //WatchKey watchKey = null;
        while(true) {
            watchKey = service.take();

            Kind<?> kind = null;
            for(WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : watchKey.pollEvents()){
                kind = watchEvent.kind();
                if(OVERFLOW == kind) {
                    continue;
                } else if (ENTRY_CREATE == kind){
                    newFile = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent).context();
                    patternMatcher = newFile.toString();
                    matcher = pattern.matcher(patternMatcher);
                    //
                    //If the file is an image
                    if(matcher.matches()){
                        //Return image to main class
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!watchKey.reset()){
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, I'm not sure but I think you should manipulate the image either from the DirectoryWatcher thread itself, or from other threads (Callable) created by the DirectoryWatcher thread.
In that last scenario, the DirectoryWatcher would start a thread(callable) whenever a new image is detected in the folder.  Each created threads would just do their job with the new file and then terminates.  To make that I suggest you take a look at ExecutorService, Callable and Future.  With that api you will have no thread synchonization to worry about.

Otherwise, if you really want the main thread to do something each time the directory watcher finds a new image, your main thread would have to first create a blocking collection, like [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), pass it to the DirectoryWatcher thread before starting it.
The DirectoryWatcher thread would then add file names to the queue whenever it needs to, and the main thread could loop forever, calling the [take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take()) method of the blocking queue.
Have in mind that if you do that, the main thread could do nothing else than listen to filenames returned from the DirectoryWatcher.
And since there would be only one thread executing for all file found, it would be less performant than the solution with the ExecutorService,Callable,Future proposed above in the case more than one image are copied in the folder at the same time.